# JavaScript, how to check if part of string is one string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

So, I have an Array with with Strings in it. Now I want to check if a String contains at least one of thoose Strings in the Array.

```
{
    "filter" : [
        "ABDC",
        "ADBAC"
    ]
}

var string1 = "ABCD";
var string2 = "ABDC sample";
var string3 = "ADBACABDC";
```

Now I want a function that returns `true` on `string2` & `string3` and `false` on `string1`

Whats the best way to achive this on node.js?

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: some and includes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and for each entry check if the string [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the filter :

```js
const data = {
  "filter" : [
      "ABDC",
      "ADBAC"
  ]
}

var string1 = "ABCD";
var string2 = "ABDC sample";
var string3 = "ADBACABDC";

const check = (arr, string) => {
  return arr.some(e => string.includes(e));
}

console.log(check(data.filter, string1));
console.log(check(data.filter, string2));
console.log(check(data.filter, string3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Will be something like that

```
function checkString(stringsArray, stringToCheck) {
   return !!stringsArray.find((str) => stringToCheck.indexOf(str) > -1);
}
```

Then you'll need to call this function with your filter and each of your strings you want to check:

```
const filter = [
        "ABDC",
        "ADBAC"
    ];

var string1 = "ABCD";
var string2 = "ABDC sample";
var string3 = "ADBACABDC";

checkString(filter, string1);
checkString(filter, string2);
checkString(filter, string3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [**RegExp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
let filter =["ABDC","ADBAC"]

var string1 = "ABCD";
var string2 = "ABDC sample";
var string3 = "ADBACABDC";

let match = (input) =>filter.some(e=>{
    let regEx = new RegExp(e, 'g')
    return regEx.test(input)
})

console.log(match(string1))
console.log(match(string2))
console.log(match(string3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
var obj = { "filter" : [ "ABDC", "ADBAC" ]  } ;

function test(str) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < obj["filter"].length; i++ ) {
    patt = new RegExp(obj["filter"][i]) ;
    if ( patt.test(str) ) break;
  }
  console.log(str + " ==> " + patt.test(str) )
}

test( "ABCD" ) ;
test( "ABDC sample" ) ;
test( "ADBACABDC" ) ;
```